# PostgreSQL priority between CTE and real table

Tags: postgresql, cte, database-internals

Is there some kind of priority ranks assigned to CTE and table name ? For instance, if I have a table called `table_a` in the public schema, and I create a CTE table named `table_a` using `WITH`, which table will be taken if I use `table_a` in the `SELECT` query ?

```
--as an example
CREATE TABLE table_a (
  id serial
);

WITH table_a AS (
     SELECT id
     FROM another_table
     )
SELECT *
FROM table_a --> which table is this ?
;
```

Comment: I think it evaluates CTE's first, before going out and searching for database tables/views - likely a question for stackoverflow, etc., though...

Comment: @DPSSpatial we exist too. ;)

Comment: @EvanCarroll who...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL searches the CTE namespace with `scanNameSpaceForCTE` as the very first thing it does in [`searchRangeTableForRel`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/08ea7a2291db21a618d19d612c8060cda68f1892/src/backend/parser/parse_relation.c#L332)

```
if (!relation->schemaname)
{
    cte = scanNameSpaceForCTE(pstate, refname, &ctelevelsup);
    if (!cte)
        isenr = scanNameSpaceForENR(pstate, refname);
}
```

If there is no schema

1. check for a CTE
2. check for a "Ephemeral Named Relation"

This is similar to [Variable Shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) if there is no namespace, and what the spec otherwise demands.

Everything in PostgreSQL has a namespace, if you want to address the table as compared to the CTE, consider providing [*(qualifying)*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/203696/2639) the namespace.

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS VALUES (0);

WITH foo AS ( VALUES (1) )
SELECT *
FROM ( VALUES (2) ) AS foo   -- inline virtual-table
UNION TABLE foo              -- CTE
UNION TABLE public.foo;      -- explicitly qualified the namespace;
```